# WSO2 API Manager (1.9.0) - Set Expire Date/Validity Time Via cURL

Tags: curl, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

When using the WSO2 AM via the Store it is possible to set a Validity Time, so that the access token expire time can be increased/decreased.

Is it possible to set the Validity Time via cURL when generating a new token?

E.g.
Normal token generation command:

`curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -H "Authorization: Basic userToken, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" localhost:8243/token`

`{"scope":"am_application_scope default","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1367,"access_token":"1234456677890"}`

Possible token generation command with setting validity time:

`curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -d "validity_time=99999" -H "Authorization: Basic userToken, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" localhost:8243/token`

`{"scope":"am_application_scope default","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":99999,"access_token":"1234456677890"}`

What is the correct command to use for setting this?  The reason for this, is because I would like the users of the API Manager be able to set the expire date via a Java API client that we offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box. You can implement it by writing a custom OAuth Grant Type. Please refer [1] for more details on how to write a custom OAuth Grant Type.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Writing+a+Custom+OAuth+2.0+Grant+Type

Comment: Glad it helped! If you can, please share the code here. It will help others to save couple of hours!